# I did the GTA Online tutorial but now it says I have to do the tutorial again

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I’m level 74 right now and have been playing with my friends forever now but one day I wanted to redo my character's appearance. I paid the $100,000 it asked for and after that, it now says I can’t join my friends because I haven’t done the GTA Online Tutorial. This is on the PS4.

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure it's just a bug for everyone atm, all my friends are getting the same issue. a workaround for me on PS4 is opening your friend's PS Profile and clicking on View Details (for GTA 5) and joining from there.